# difference between reference to a box of an int and reference to an int in rust?

Tags: pointers, reference, rust, mutable

Well, i've recently started to programm in Rust and I need help.
Here is my code. It should take a reference to a heap allocated int and to change it value.

```
let mut boxed_int = box 5;
let _ref_to_int   = &mut *boxed_int;   // why it is &int ???
*_ref_to_int      = 10;

let mut boxed_int = box 5;
let _ref_to_int   = &mut boxed_int;
*_ref_to_int      = box 10;
```

Does the last line delete 5 from the heap and allocates 10 at the same address ?
Or 5 is not deleted and now pointer points to another address on the heap with the value of 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your program with explicit type annotations:

```
let mut boxed_int:   Box<int> = box 5;
let mut _ref_to_int: &mut int = &mut *boxed_int;      // (1)
*_ref_to_int = 10;

let mut boxed_int:   Box<int> = box 5;
let mut _ref_to_int: &mut Box<int> = &mut boxed_int;  // (2)
*_ref_to_int = box 10;
```

A small recap: `Box` is a smart pointer which encapsulates heap allocation. It allocates sufficient space to store a value of its contained type and keeps track of this memory, deallocating it when it goes out of scope. Essentially this provides value-like semantics.

In the first piece of code in (1) you borrow `boxed_int` content: first, `*` dereferences `Box<int>`, obtaining `int`, and then `&mut` immediately creates a reference, resulting in `&mut int`. Naturally, `*_ref_to_int = 10` overwrites the box contents, so `boxed_int` will contain 10 after this. No allocations or deallocations happen here.

In the second piece of code in (2) you borrow `boxed_int` itself, so `_ref_to_int` is of type `&mut Box<int>`. `*_ref_to_int = box 10` then replaces the boxed value itself. Because the old boxed value goes out of scope immediately, its destructor is invoked, and corresponding heap memory is freed. Then a new piece of memory is allocated on the heap, and a pointer to it is written instead of the just freed one (`box 10`).

So,

> Does the last line delete 5 from the heap and allocates 10 at the same address ?

Yes and no. Last line deletes 5 from the heap and allocates 10, but not at the same address, of course. The actual address will likely be different, but you won't notice it because `Box` does not expose its numerical value.

Comment: `Naturally, *_ref_to_int = 10 overwrites the box contents`

Not "natural" at all really. If things were how you mention (derefence, then creating a mut reference) you'd actually be copying the boxed int into the stack, in a new location, and modifying _that_ through the reference. So rust _is_ doing some magic here.